# Is it possible to run a macro every day at a time?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to know if it is possible to have a macro executed daily at 7:00 am.

Would this be done through a macro, or through some visual basic component?

Comment: For a similar situation I was in, I used Windows task scheduler to open a specific workbook which had the macro I wanted to run, in the `Workbook_Open()` event.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with the `Workbook_Open()` event is that if you still need to action on your workbook manually during the day, the macro will launch, which can be source of errors depending on what your macro does.

Alternatively, you can use the Windows Task Scheduler as mentionned above to run a VB Script that will run the macro in your workbook.

```
  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False 'turn off alerts
  xlApp.Application.Visible = False  'keeps Excel hidden
  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyPath\MyWorkbook.xlsm", 0, False)
  xlApp.Run "MACRO_NAME"
  xlBook.Save
  xlBook.Close
  xlApp.Quit
  Set xlBook = Nothing
  Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Just type your script within notepad and save as .vbs (and then have the Windows Task Scheduler to run you .vbs).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways that I know of to do this, neither of which are perfect.

The first is the `Application.OnTime` method in VBA (documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime)). This method will schedule another method to be run at a specific time. I haven't thoroughly testing this function, so I don't know if the schedule will be preserved across excel restarts or even workbook closures.

Another option is the Windows Task Scheduler(thanks [Mistella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9259306/mistella)). You can set up a basic task within the task scheduler to open a specific workbook in excel at a given time at a given interval and have the code you wish to be run within the Workbook's `Open` event. Within that event you could check the time. If the time is close enough to your designated task scheduler time you could perform the work you needed to do, save the workbook, and close it, all without user interaction.