# Run excel macro at midnight and 7am every day

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run a macro every day at midnight and 7am.
This is the code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    RefreshAllDataConn
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("00:00:00"), "RefreshAllDataConn"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("07:00:00"), "RefreshAllDataConn"
End Sub
```

I thought it would work, but apparently it only runs them once, while I need them to keep running without having to close and reopen the file, also I want to do it using VBA only.
Can someone help me?

Comment: If you close the workbook, the code will not run. You have to leave Excel running with that workbook open at all times. It would be better to create a .NET application and leave that running instead.

Comment: I  know that I need to keep the workbook open, my issue is that even if it's open it only runs once and not every day like I'd want it to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52278439/is-it-possible-to-run-a-macro-every-day-at-a-time

Comment: `Application.OnTime`  sets up a *one time* task - once it has run it doesn't recur.  When `RefreshAllDataConn` is done with its work then it needs to set up the next run.  Using Task Scheduler (see the the linked post) is a better approach here.

Comment: Configure the workbook to run the macro on file open, then save & close when all done. Then in Windows, use the built-in Task Scheduler to launch excel.exe with full path of workbook as parameter. May need to make changes to Trigger settings to "wake computer to run it", depends on your computer power settings.